# transfer a "32bit float" variable

Tags: c, floating-point, spi

I need to transfer many "32 bit float" variables from one DSP to another DSP through SPI.

However, the register is alaways 16bit that I need to split the "32bit float" variable into two parts.

I used the C type union like

```
union mytype {
  float a;
  uint16_t b[2];
};
```

It works well but I get the new problem that it is hard to know whether the received 16bit data is for b[0] or b[1] at startup. (The two DSP may power on at different time, so the 1st data may not always be b[0]).

I tried to split the 32bit float into 4 bytes, and when I transfer the 16bit, I add a tag before the 8bit data. That also works perfect. But I got performance slow down doubled.

Is there any way to transfer the "32bit float" by two 16bit data? I known my number range is within "0.0000001 ~ 1000000 "(both +/-). Or any other suggestions? I also think about hand-shake on SPI between two DSPs, but it seems to make it complex. I just want to capture the startup data is b[0], then I can receive everything in sequence.

THanks

Comment: So what you want is to split a float into two 16-bit chunks, each of them also carrying information about if it's the first chunk or the second, right?

Comment: This is too broad. Read about [floating point format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format). You can try to reuse unused bits in exponent part (because your numbers are relatively close to 1), or drop lower bits of fraction part.

Comment: Do you really need to send it repetitively even if the receiver is not available? Why don't you send after an ACK for example?

Comment: What you need is a *preamble* (also known as *syncword*): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syncword.

Comment: Note: If a bit is used to identify first chuck vs 2nd chunk, the reconstruction needs to expect the 2 halves in a consistent order.  This prevents combining 2 halves from different original numbers should a sporadic hiccup occur and one of the halves is loss/corrupted.

Answer (score 2):

Akin to @Cantfindname idea, but remove 2 bits out of the exponent.  No precision loss.

Further, reject any out of sequence pairs to prevent forming a `float` from halves that do not belong together.

I see @Patricia Shanahan has commented that.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void encode(float f, uint16_t *u16) {
  volatile union {
    float f;
    uint32_t u;
  } x;
  x.f = f;
  x.u -= 0x30000000u;
  u16[0] = 0x0000u | ((x.u >>  0) & 0x7FFFu);
  u16[1] = 0x8000u | ((x.u >> 17) & 0x4000u) | ((x.u >> 15) & 0x3FFFu);
}

int decode(const uint16_t *u16, float *f) {
  volatile union {
    float f;
    uint32_t u;
  } x;
  if (((u16[0] & 0x8000u) != 0x0000u) || ((u16[1] & 0x8000u) != 0x8000u)) {
    printf("Fail\n");
    return 1; // fail
  }
  x.u =  (u16[1] & 0x4000ul) << 17;
  x.u |= (u16[1] & 0x3FFFul) << 15;
  x.u |= (u16[0] & 0x7FFFu);
  x.u += 0x30000000u;
  *f = x.f;
  return 0;
}

int test(float f) {
  uint16_t u[2];
  encode(f, u);
  float f2;
  decode(u, &f2);
  if (f != f2) {
    printf("%.8e %.8e\n", f, f2);
  }
  return f != f2;
}

#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
  float f;
  for (f= 0.0000001; f <= 1000000.0; f = nextafterf(f,2*f)) {
    test(f);
    test(-f);
  }
  return 0;
  puts("Done");
}
```

Given the range "0.0000001 ~ 1000000", the MSBits of a [binary32 float](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) are always <kbd>s011</kbd> to <kbd>s100</kbd>.  <kbd>s</kbd> is the sign bit.  By subtracting 3, the range is <kbd>s000</kbd> <kbd>s001</kbd>.  That allows ignoring the middle 2 bits and then only 30 bits of the 32 bit float need to be maintained.  Sending 2 16-bit messages, each with a "phase" bit and a 15-bit portion of the 30-bits, allows total reconstruction of the original `float`.

Should the receiving end receive a message out-of-phase, it should ignore messages until a consecutive phase-0/phase-1 combination arrives.

---

By subtracting other values, at least 1 more bit can be ignored, allowing an additional sequence bit number, further insuring proper re-combination.  After all it appears only 340,000,000 combinations of the 4,294,967,296 `floats` are used.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea if you can live with some minimal loss of precision on large numbers:

Lose the two least significant bits of the float (bits 0 and 1). Then rearrange the bits of the float so that:

- b[0] contains a 0 and bits 16..2 of the float
- b[1] contains a 1 and bits 31..17 of the float

Then, when you receive a 16 bit integer, check the most significant bit to see if it is a b[0] or a b[1], and reconstruct your float with 2 zeros on bits 0 and 1.

The loss of precision should be minimal on the range of numbers that you need, and this conversion only requires logical operations, so it should be fast.

Comment: By dropping the last to bits, numbers like 0.9876543 and 0.9876542 both get sent as 0.9876542.  If tolerable, a good idea.

Comment: @chux Yes, that is the loss of precision that I am talking about :)

Comment: Given the narrow range, you could take the two bits out of the leading exponent bits, rather than the significand. That would keep the original precision, but reduce the supported range.

Comment: The range is 0.0000001 ~ 1000000 so the exponent is only -24~20 and he needs only 6 bits for the exponent

Answer (score 1):

If the payload data does not include NaNs, periodically send two all-bits-one chunks. When the receiver starts up, it scans the data until it sees such a pair, and then takes the next chunk with at least one zero bit as a b[0], the following chunk as its b[1] etc.

Each subsequent time it sees an all-bits-one pair, it should ignore it.

You would have a trade-off between how much bandwidth you waste sending unneeded all-bit-one pairs, and how much data the receive drops before getting in sync and processing real data on start-up.

Answer (score 0):

if that range is absolute you only need 28 bits to express it. That leaves you 4 to do with what you want. I would reccomend making the first 2 bits of either uint16 an identifier so that when you recieve it you can perform some operation on it to decide which part of the integer it is.

Comment: Please detail how "0.0000001 ~ 1000000 "(both +/-)" only need 20 bits to express it.  I thought it was any +/- 6 or 7 digit numbers over an exponent range 10^-7 to 10^6.  Or about 23 (significand) + 4 (expo) + 1 sign = 28 bits, but that may be over-conservative.

Comment: I think you're right, but you still have bits to sign